# Specify generic type parameter in Scala

Tags: scala, types

I'm new to Scala and have generic method written in Java:

```
public interface Context{
    <T> Optional<T> get(String parameterName);
}
```

and Scala class:

```
class Mcls(ctx: Context){
    val str = ctx.[Optional[String]]get("str").get //error
}
```

Is there a way to specify generic type parameter shorted then `asInstanceOf[Optional[String]]` in Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asInstanceOf[Optional[String]]` is just incorrect in this case, even though it happens to work due to type erasure. To specify the parameter directly you'd write

```
ctx.get[String]("str")
```

which is the direct equivalent to `ctx.<String> get("str")` in Java.

Answer (score 3):

`val str:  Optional[String] = ctx.get("str")` should do it.

And so should `val str = ctx.get[String]("str")`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use **type alias** to short this, and it's unnecessary to **cast** the type.

```
  type MY_TYPE = Optional[String]
  val str: MY_TYPE = ctx.get("str") //it's unnecessary get in here, since the `get` method already return `MY_TYPE`, and specify type after variable, the compiler will auto infer the generic type for this.
  println(str)
```